# How to install new iOS base SDK in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I'm creating an iOS project and I have reason to suspect that my app runs well on iOS 5.1, but not on iOS 5.0.  However, I want it to run perfectly on iOS 5.0.  The problem is, I can't figure out how to use iOS 5.0 as my base SDK in Xcode. I've found the place where I can change sdks (Target > Build Settings), but the only iOS SDK listed there is 5.1.  How can I install base SDK iOS 5.0 in Xcode?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't use iOS 5.0 as your base SDK. As long as 5.0 or less is your deployment target, it will launch on iOS 5. Then, you'd just need to test on iOS 5 and iOS 5.1 and fix any issues you have (you can test in both simulators in Xcode, just download the iOS 5.0 simulator from the preferences panel in Xcode--although if you do have an iOS 5.0 device, making sure it runs smoothly there too is important).

Comment: That's right; set the "Deployment Target" to 5.0 and test on a device running 5.0. It won't matter that it's built against 5.1